# Error while instanciating an object with the same name of an import but different

Tags: java

I use SLF4j library in java to get some easier way to log my application and I get the following problem.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

[...]

```
FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(LOGS_FILE.getAbsolutePath());
java.util.logging.Logger javaLogger = new java.util.logging.Logger ("logger");
javaLogger.addHandler(fh);
SimpleFormatter sf = new SimpleFormatter();
fh.setFormatter(sf);
```

So, I use SLF4J to log in my logger and I get back the jdkLogger in a file Handler to return a file when the application close. But, I get the following error when I try to launch my application :

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
>       The constructor Logger(String) is not visible"

Totality of the class :

```
package fr.theblackdev.BungeeNetworkManager;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;



public class Main {

    public static final File DIR = new File("");
    public static final File CONFIG_DIR = new File(DIR.getAbsolutePath(), "BNMConfig");
    public static final File LOGS_DIR = new File(DIR.getAbsolutePath(), "logs");

    public static final File TEMPLATE_FILE = new File(CONFIG_DIR, "template.yml");
    public static File LOGS_FILE;

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static final String CONSOLE_PREFIX = "BungeeNetworkManager » ";

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(new Date());

        DIR.mkdirs();
        CONFIG_DIR.mkdirs(); //TODO A Décommenter
        LOGS_DIR.mkdirs();

        Date starting_date = new Date();
        LOGS_FILE = new File(LOGS_DIR, "logs  " + starting_date.getDate() + "_" + starting_date.getMonth() + "_" + 
                starting_date.getHours() + "h" + starting_date.getMinutes() + "m" + starting_date.getSeconds() + "s.txt");

        try {
            LOGS_FILE.createNewFile();
            if(!TEMPLATE_FILE.exists()) {TEMPLATE_FILE.createNewFile();}
        }
        catch (IOException e) { 
            logger.error("{}Le programme n'a pas pu créer les fichiers nécessaires à son fonctionnement !", CONSOLE_PREFIX);
            logger.error("{}", e);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        try {
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler(LOGS_FILE.getAbsolutePath());
            java.util.logging.Logger javaLogger = new java.util.logging.Logger ("logger");
            javaLogger.addHandler(fh);
            SimpleFormatter sf = new SimpleFormatter();
            fh.setFormatter(sf);

        } catch (Exception e) {}

        System.out.println(LOGS_DIR.getAbsolutePath()); 


            //TODO Mettre dans un fichier le logger

        logger.info("{}Démarrage terminé !", CONSOLE_PREFIX);

    }

}
```

Comment: @Aominè it's not his constructor. He's trying to use a constructor that isn't visible. That won't work, so use a different constructor. Although I'm not sure why you'd even use `java.util.logging` here, when you have SLF4J in use...I'd recommend using Logback instead.

Comment: @Kayaman just realised `java.util.....`, thanks.

Comment: @here Sorry for misunderstanding, I give you the totallity of the class its better...

Comment: java.util.logging.Logger constructor is protected and is done on purpose not to be able to create it directly but use its static methods.  `java.util.logging.Logger javaLogger= java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger( "logger" );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't instantiate `Logger` from outside of the class due to `protected` access of its constructor. `Logger` class provides static method `getLogger(String name)` to create an instance of `Logger`. Take a look at an example of use of this method:

```
java.util.logging.Logger logger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("logger");
```

You might also want to have a look at Java API documentation to see more details about the use of this method.

Comment: I was writting the same thing but thanks ... I'm a bit retard ;) Good Night

Comment: Maybe next time you will be be more lucky, and I'm a retard one :-) Good night!

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you use like this

```
import java.io.IOException;; 
import java.util.logging.Logger; 
public class LoggerExample {    
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(LoggerExample.class.getName());   
public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, IOException {  
    LOGGER.info("Logger Name: "+LOGGER.getName());          
    LOGGER.warning("Can cause ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException");             
    //An array of size 3        
int []a = {1,2,3};  
    int index = 4;      
LOGGER.config("index is set to "+index);                try{            System.out.println(a[index]);       
}catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
{           LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception occur", ex);        }           
} }
```

Comment: Thx for the modifications :)

Comment: Edited pls check

Comment: Exception might be in this line 

java.util.logging.Logger javaLogger = new java.util.logging.Logger ("logger");
     Wht about using like this

java.util.logging.Logger javaLogger =  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger ("logger");